# Temporizador en C++ con milésimas de segundo. Problemas con el tiempo de pausa

Tags: c++

Como adelante el título del post. Estoy iniciando en el mundo de C++. Quiero realizar un temporizador pero que el tiempo sea lo mas exacto posible (tiempo real, no una simple cuenta regresiva), agregando los milisegundos. Y a partir de esto último, es decir, agregar los milisegundos, es donde comienzan los problemas. Si solo lo dejo hasta los segundos, dandole una pausa de 1000 milisegundos, todo parece fundionar bien, pero en el momento en que le agrego para dejarlo mas completo los milisegundos (dandole pausa en microsegundos, 1000 = 1 milisegundo, ya que paso todo el tiempo a milisegundos), el tiempo pasa o muy rápido o muy lento.
Les dejo el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

void countdown(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds) {
  int total_milliseconds = (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000 + milliseconds;
  int current_milliseconds = total_milliseconds;
  //auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while (current_milliseconds > 0) {
  auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    current_milliseconds -= 1;
    int remaining_milliseconds = current_milliseconds % 1000;
    int remaining_seconds = current_milliseconds / 1000 % 60;
    int remaining_minutes = current_milliseconds / 1000 / 60 % 60;
    int remaining_hours = current_milliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", remaining_hours, remaining_minutes, remaining_seconds, remaining_milliseconds);
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    
    int wait_time = current_milliseconds - elapsed_time;
    //std::cout << wait_time << " ";
    if (wait_time > 0) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
    }
  }
  Beep(440, 1000);
}

int main() {
  countdown(0, 0, 2, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

He tratado de incorporar el hecho de tomar el tiempo y descontarlo, para que sin importar las tareas del procesador o el tiempo en que el mismo tarde, siempre se pueda descontar exactamente lo mismo.
Otra cosa, tampoco logro que solo muestre una línea y en cada frame me borre la pantalla.
Sé que en alguna lógica debo estar fallando. Espero me puedan guiar, saludos Leopoldo.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `int` suele ser de 32 bits así que el máximo tiempo que puedes guardar en milisegundos sería mas o menos 2000 millones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo sin 'dormir' el hilo de ejecución mediante estos pasos, en la función `countdown:

1. Obtienes el total de milisegundos que representan la cuenta atrás.
2. Obtienes el tiempo actual (esta variable sera 'pisada' mas
   adelante).
3. Obtienes el tiempo futuro que se obtiene de sumarle al tiempo actual
   los milisegundos de la cuenta atrás (esta sera una constante).

**En el bucle while, mientras este continue:**

1. Obtenemos el tiempo actual, pisando la variable.
2. Obtenemos el tiempo pasado (`elapsed_time`) en milisegundos del temporizador, que se obtiene de restar a la constante de tiempo futuro, el tiempo actual.
3. Si este valor es igual o menor a 0, se rompe el bucle.
4. Se obtienen, a partir de `elapsed_time` todos los datos necesarios para el temporizador (las conversiones a horas, minutos etc). Se limpia la consola y se imprimen los valores.

**Si se rompe el bucle:**

1. Se limpia la consola y se imprime "00:00:00.000"

De esa manera, al usar el tiempo futuro y recalcular el tiempo actual y la diferencia entre ellos constantemente, el temporizador se mantiene actualizado sin desfasarse, aca te dejo la implementación:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

void countdown(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
{
  int total_milliseconds = (hours * 3600000) + (minutes * 60000) + (1000 * seconds) + milliseconds;
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto FUTURE_TIME = start + std::chrono::milliseconds(total_milliseconds);

  while (true)
  {
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(FUTURE_TIME - start).count();
    
    if(elapsed_time <= 0) {
      break;
    }

    int remaining_milliseconds = elapsed_time % 1000;
    int remaining_seconds = (elapsed_time / 1000) % 60;
    int remaining_minutes = (elapsed_time / 60000) % 60;
    int remaining_hours = (elapsed_time / 3600000);

    system("CLS");
    printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", remaining_hours, remaining_minutes, remaining_seconds, remaining_milliseconds);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
  }
  system("CLS");
  printf("\r00:00:00.000");
  Beep(440, 1000);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  countdown(0, 0, 5, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Por otro lado la cantidad de milisegundos totales se debe calcular de esta forma:

```
int total_milliseconds = (hours * 3600000) + (minutes * 60000) + (1000 * seconds) + milliseconds;
```

Si la consola se borra tan rápido que no puedes ver el tiempo entonces si puedes considerar dormir el hilo principal, Por 100ms por ejemplo y la pantalla se actualizaría cada ese tiempo, esto no afecta el resto del programa. Aunque si pones un sleep de 100ms y el temporizador lo configuras en 50ms entonces no te mostrara el resultado pasados 100ms.

Comment: Buenas noches infinit3Loop, me has provocado un shock mental en el buen sentído. Tu lógica es gigante. Funciona muy bien, sí he visto que repite centésimas de segundo, pero los segundos son exactos!
Aún estoy tratando de entender la lógica y cómo es que tarda 1 ms exacto (me va a llevar tiempo entender). Te juro que me duele y me va a doler la cabeza por un tiempo. Interpreto que repite porque quizás el start dentro del while lo hace tan rápido que no alcanza a descontar nada con la constante verdad? Te mando un fuerte abrazo!

Comment: La clave esta en recalcular la hora actual en cada iteración y obtener la diferencia con la constante del tiempo objetivo (FUTURE_TIME), a medida que pasa el tiempo esa diferencia se va lógicamente achicando y si esa diferencia es 0 o menor entonces se detiene el temporizador. Si solo pones 1 milisegundo la diferencia entre el tiempo actual y el objetivo solo es de +1 ms

Comment: Seguramente el bucle se rompa en la primera iteración o como mucho en la segunda.

Comment: En lugar de un `cls` puedes poner un `\r` al inicio de del string del `printf`.

Comment: @Mateo por no mencionar que es independiente del sistema operativo, gracias

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Hola, cómo estas? Gracias una vez más por tu aporte. Te quería preguntrar si para dicha tarea es correcto que se utilice "high_resolution_clock", o es mejor usar "steady_clock "?
Otra consulta, me puedes recomendar editores para C++, uso visual studio code, pero a veces hace cosas extrañas. Saludos!

Comment: Yo uso Dev-C++, en específico [está](https://www.embarcadero.com/es/free-tools/dev-cpp) version, con respecto a tu otra duda, lee la documentación de la librería, o haz otra pregunta, los comentarios no son para conversaciones, saludos.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ ten en cuenta que `system_clock` se ve afectado por cambios de hora ya sean automáticos o forzados por el usuario. Sería más preciso y menos problemático usar [`steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

Answer (score 3):

Según [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), `sleep_for` puede tardar más tiempo del indicado.

Puedes suspender un hilo en cualquier momento pero no controlar exactamente cuando debe continuar, ya que el sistema operativo es el encargado de asignar los tiempos de ejecución a cada hilo.

Naturalmente, cuanto menor sea el tiempo de espera, más se va a notar el tiempo adicional.

Algunas opciones son:

- Aumentar la prioridad del proceso. En Windows puedes hacerlo con [`SetPriorityClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setpriorityclass) y [`SetThreadPriority`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority).

  ```
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
  ```
- Por más que la prioridad del proceso aumente, no será suficiente. En lugar de suspender el hilo, ponlo en bucle hasta que se cumpla el tiempo. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
  using duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  auto start  = clock::now();
  auto end = start + 1ms;
  while (clock::now() < end){}
  ```
- O considera usar alguna otra función propia del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, un [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-waitable-timer-objects). La propia documentación brinda el siguiente ejemplo:

  ```
  HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
  LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

  liDueTime.QuadPart = -100000000LL;

  // Create an unnamed waitable timer.
  hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
  if (NULL == hTimer)
  {
      printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return 1;
  }

  printf("Waiting for 10 seconds...\n");

  // Set a timer to wait for 10 seconds.
  if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
  {
      printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return 2;
  }

  // Wait for the timer.
  if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
      printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
  else
      printf("Timer was signaled.\n");
  ```

[Puedes ver una pregunta similar a la tuya en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13397571).

Comment: Buenas noches Mateo. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme. Voy a ponerme a estudiar tus apuntes.